# Do-while loop only executes twice after user inputs Y

Tags: java, user-input, do-while

I am having issues with my do while statement in my program. I want it to repeat the method in the case when the user inputs Y, then quit when the user inputs N and return to the menu.

After the second user input, the program no longer reads the Y/N nor executes the statement. If I can get some help on this, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
 switch(menuChoice)
          {
            // Insert
              case 1: 
                do {
                  System.out.println("Inserting to heap..." );
                  System.out.println();
                  ProcessInfo insertPI = readFile.readFile(rowIncrement++);
                  Integer K = insertPI.getPriority();
                  Entry<Integer, ProcessInfo> insertEntry = new EntryKV(K, insertPI);
                  maxHeap.insert(insertEntry);

                  System.out.println("Process ID: " + insertPI.getProcessID() + " and priority number " + insertPI.getPriority() + " have been inserted.");
                  System.out.println("Would you like to insert more? Please enter Y for yes and N for no");
                  YN = scan.next().charAt(0);
                }
                while (YN == 'Y' || YN == 'y');
                
                
            
              if (YN == 'N' || YN == 'n'){
                    break;
                  }
                  else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Returning to menu.");
                    break;
                  }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? I'm guessing that you should replace `scan.next()` with `scan.nextLine()` because of how you're inputting your data.

Comment: I did yeah,  but it didn't really help. I will try that out real quick.

Comment: No, @Amongalen, that is not the problem. In general nextLine() is a bad idea; if you want to read lines-at-a-time, use `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n")` instead. Now you don't need to throw in blank nextLine() statements which break if the user ever does use that spacebar.